# Is there a way to extract text information from a postscript file? (.ps .eps)

Tags: python, image, text, postscript

I want to extract the text information contained in a postscript image file (the captions to my axis labels).
These images were generated with pgplot. I have tried ps2ascii and ps2txt on Ubuntu but they didn't produce any useful results. Does anyone know of another method?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely that pgplot drew the fonts in  the text directly with lines rather than using text. Especially since pgplot is designed to output to a huge range of devices including plotters where you would have to do this.

Edit:

If you have enough plots to be worth
    the effort than it's a very simple
    image processing task. Convert each
    page to something like tiff, in mono
    chrome Threshold the image to binary, 
    the text will be max pixel value.

Use a template matching technique.
    If you have a limited set of
    possible labels then just match the
    entire label, you can even start
    with a template of the correct size
    and rotation. Then just flag each
    plot as containing label[1-n], no
    need to read the actual text.

If you
    don't know the label then you can
    still do OCR fairly easily, just
    extract the region around the axis,
    rotate it for the vertical - and use
    Google's free OCR lib

If you have pgplot you can even
    build the training set for OCR or
    the template images directly rather
    than having to harvest them from the
    image list

Comment: The postscript pgplot example http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~tjp/pgplot/example1.ps.gz does exactly this.  OCR techniques are an alternative, but it might be equally fast to type the captions in, depending..

Comment: @ DSM: I'm actually interested in reverse-engineering this. Using your example, I want to extract the string "y = x² exp(-x)" from the figure example1.ps

Comment: @Hooloovoo: I get that, but Martin's right: in that example, the text itself isn't there, only the lines that make up the characters.  (That's what I meant by "does exactly this".)  You should look at the files yourself to make sure.  I can only think of two plausible ways to back out the text: you could apply OCR methods to a bitmapped image, or (since you can presumably make a dictionary of new captions) possibly parse the postscript directly.

Comment: Bummer, I've got 4000 files I need to do that for. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: OCR - should be relatively easy, you have perfect digital copies of the files, the text is in a known place with a known rotation and in the same font. If you only have a limited set of possible labels then a direct template match could easily just tell you that the image has a certain label from a list.

Comment: @ Martin - I'll see if I can find any OCR packages in Python.  As you say, I know the location of the text on all images so it should be possible to extract it. pytesser looks promising but I'm not sure it will work on Ubuntu. Will check it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ is the best ocr lib, since it's by google and they are a python shop I assume there will be excellent python bindings. Although - if you only have a few 100 possible labels I would use direct template matching